# Change Product name without reinstalling

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I have a Winform app deployed with clickonce by about 200 users. We have to change the name on link in the start menu, but changing it in product name product has no effect once user update their app.

Reading some post I found someone saying that the solution is to remove and reistall the app, but most of our users don't even know what the control panel is, so make them remove the app is not doable.

Is there a way to force the new name in start menu?

UPDATE:
we deploy it tooday and see that most users has the new name. we will wait some times to see if other will get the update too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users will have to reinstall the app, there is sadly no way you can change this, the problem where the name doesn't update is simply something that may update once the computer has restarted or wont update at all (Many of these things are saved in registry and the windows store system doesn't refresh that often)